# Flutter Why my textfield lose the value when I dont focus on it?

Tags: flutter

I made a class and it has a controller and a widget that includes a padding within a textfield.
Now when I change the focus from the textfield to something else it lose the value.
this is my code.
`

```
class RxInput {
  final String hindText;
  final bool obscureText;
  Widget widget;
  final TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController ();
  String get value => controller.text;
  RxInput (this.hindText,context,{this.obscureText = false}) {
    widget = Padding (
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          shadowColor: Colors.blue.shade200,
          elevation: 5.0,
          child:TextField(
            controller: controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: hindText,
              border: InputBorder.none,
              alignLabelWithHint: true,
            ),
            obscureText: obscureText,
          )
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question. You should initialize your variable in the `initState` instead of `build`.